# Trying to connect files to my main.py file, gives me an error

Tags: python

I've been trying out python for the past few days and have been coding a basic terminal thingy for fun. I decided to move my functions to other files and use the `import` feature to connect them. My IDE (repl.it) tells me I can just import the filename and call the functions in my main.py, but the built-in interpreter gives me a NameError. Here's my code:

main.py

```
import functions

def terminal() :
  command = input('')
  if command == 'login' :
    functions.login()
  if command == 'logout' :
    functions.logout()
  if command == 'info' :
    info.info()


print('Welcome to the terminal. Please start by entering a command.')
terminal()
```

functions.py

```
import main

def login() :
  enteredcode = input('Enter Passcode: ')
  if enteredcode == code[0] :
    loggedIn == True
    print('Login Successful!')
    print('Logged in as: ' + user[0])
    main.terminal()
  if enteredcode == code[1] :
    loggedIn == True
    print('Login Successful!')
    print('Logged in as: ' + user[1])
    main.terminal()
  else :
    print('Incorrect Code. Please Try Again.')
    login()
    

def logout() :
  if loggedIn == True :
    loggedIn == False
    print('Logged Out.')
    main.terminal()
    return
  elif loggedIn == False :
    print('You are already logged out.')
    main.terminal()

user = ['user1', 'user2']
code = ['2001', '6969']
loggedIn = False
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import functions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
```

UPDATE: Fixed! I think it was the circular import that messed it up.

Comment: Can you add the full error which it prints out?

Comment: I pasted exactly your code into the same two files on [`repl.it`](https://repl.it/repls/ProbableSuperbMarketing#main.py) and got to the login prompt. That said, what you've created here is a circular import so the rest of your code won't actually work.

Comment: Have you made sure your functions.py file is in the same directory as your main.py file?

Comment: Not getting your error and I am getting the prompt, "Welcome to the terminal. Please start by entering a command."

Answer (score -1):

Your code has several issues beyond the circular imports; I took the liberty of cleaning it up a little.

1. You need to use the `global` keyword before reading global variables if you intent to modify them. You can sometimes get by without this but it's always better to be explicit. Even better would be not relying on globals at all by encapsulating state within an object, but that can be a future exercise.
2. You appear to be using `==` where you intend to be assigning; you just need a single `=` for that.
3. You can just loop forever with a `while` in your terminal function instead of recursively calling back and forth between `terminal` and `login/logout` -- that will just end up blowing your call stack.
4. Your user codes are a great place to learn about how dictionaries work.
5. I added an `exit` command as well as a warning if you try to login when already logged in.

Here:

```
#main.py
import functions

def terminal() :
  while True:
    command = input('>> ')
    if command == 'login' :
      functions.login()
    elif command == 'logout' :
      functions.logout()
    elif command == 'exit':
      print("Goodbye!")
      break
    else:
      print("Unknown command!")

print('Welcome to the terminal. Please start by entering a command.')
terminal()
```

And:

```
# functions.py
users_by_code = {
  '2001': 'user1',
  '6969': 'user2',
}
loggedIn = False

def login() :
  global loggedIn
  if loggedIn:
    print('You are already logged in!')
    return
  while True:
    enteredcode = input('Enter Passcode: ')
    user = users_by_code.get(enteredcode)
    if user:
      break
    print('Incorrect Code. Please Try Again.')
  loggedIn = True
  print('Login Successful!')
  print('Logged in as:', user)

def logout():
  global loggedIn
  if loggedIn:
    loggedIn = False
    print('Logged Out.')
  else:
    print('You are already logged out.')
```